# Prevent jQuery popups from wrapping when re-sizing browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery popup that appears when you click on a link.  The popup opens and closes fine but I want the position of the popup to remain fixed when re-sizing the browser window to prevent wrapping.

I normally use a small amount of jQuery code to prevent the browser window from re-sizing but in this particular instance it is not working properly.

jQuery Code for preventing wrapping:

```
<script src="http://wcetdesigns.com/assets/javascript/jquery.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$("[class~='floatNoWrap']").each(function () {
$(this).css("width", $(this).outerWidth());
});

});

</script>
```

jQuery Code for popups:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 



//open popup
$("#pop").click(function(){
$("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
positionPopup();
});

//close popup
$("#close").click(function(){
$("#overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
});

//open popup 2
$("#pop2").click(function(){
$("#overlay_form2").fadeIn(1000);
positionPopup();
});

//close popup 2
$("#close2").click(function(){
  $("#overlay_form2").fadeOut(500);
});


//position the popup at the center of the page
function positionPopup(){
if(!$("#overlay_form, #overlay_form2").is(':visible')){
return;
}
$("#overlay_form, #overlay_form2").css({
left: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form, #overlay_form2').width()) / 2,
top: ($(window).width() - $('#overlay_form, #overlay_form2').width()) / 3,
position:'absolute'
});
}

//maintain the popup at center of the page when browser resized
$(window).bind('resize',positionPopup);



});
```

CSS for popups:

```
#overlay_form, #overlay_form2{
font-weight:bold;
border: 2px solid;
margin: 10px 70px;
padding:35px 35px 228px 70px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 10px center;
width:600px;
color: #4F8A10;
background-color:#EDFCED;
position:absolute;
}

#pop, #pop2{
display: block;
border: 1px solid gray;
width: 65px;
text-align: center;
padding: 6px;
border-radius: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to correct the floating popups:

jQuery:

```
//position the popup at the center of the page
function positionPopup(){
if(!$("#overlay_form, #overlay_form2").is(':visible')){
return;
}
$("#overlay_form, #overlay_form2").css(("width", $(this).outerWidth())
);
}
```