# Right content in header moves under left content in header when zooming out in Safari, Chrome and Opera

Tags: html, css, header, cross-browser, zooming

I'm learning HTML CSS and right now i'm stuck at one particular problem.

Here is the [Demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/dcnh429n)

The problem is that when you zoom out in Chrome, Safari and Opera the content on the right side in the header moves under the left content in the header (a bit bad quality because I had to zoom out). [image: zoom-out header]

This is how it looks like in Firefox even if you zoom out

[image]

I want both the left side and right side content to stay in one line even if you zoom out in different browsers.

I think it has something to do with `margin` and `padding` in my code i believe, but i can't figure out where the problem lies.

Comment: Check out an answer I posted from a previous question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180040/prevent-jquery-popups-from-wrapping-when-re-sizing-browser-window][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22180040/prevent-jquery-popups-from-wrapping-when-re-sizing-browser-window

Answer (score 0):

Setting .top-head's min-width to 800px will fix this, but means users will have to scroll horizontally if they want to see the rest of the header.

```
.top-head {
  height: 45px;
  min-width: 800px;
}
```